# Error en consulta SQL tipos de datos date date y datetime son incompatibles

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Cómo le doy solución a este error? Es una consulta algo vieja (se realizó en el 2015) y al cambiar de motor SQL al 2019 aparece este tipo de error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
> The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the subtract operator.

```
select
T0.DocDate 'Fecha Pedido',
YEAR(T0.DocDate) as Año,
datename(MONTH,t0.DocDate) as Mes,
day(t0.docdate) as Dia,
T0.DocNum,
t0.NumAtCard,
T1.VendorNum,
t1.FreeTxt,
t0.CardCode,
t0.CardName,
t1.ItemCode,
t1.Dscription,
t1.Quantity,
T0.DocDate,
t1.ShipDate 'Fecha Probable de Entrega',
DATEDIFF(DAY,t0.DocDate,t1.ShipDate) as 'Dias para Entregar',
t1.U_F_Ent_Pta 'Fecha Entrega Planta',
datediff(day,t0.docdate,t1.U_F_Ent_Pta) as 'Dias Entregado',
case when t1.U_F_Ent_Pta is null then 'En Proceso' else 'Entregado' end as 'Estatus Produccion',
case when t1.U_F_Ent_Pta is null and (GETDATE()-CONVERT(time,getdate()) <= T1.ShipDate) THEN 'En Tiempo'
when datediff(day,t0.docdate,t1.U_F_Ent_Pta) <= DATEDIFF(DAY,t0.DocDate,t1.ShipDate) then 'En Tiempo'
else 'Atrasado' end as 'Estatus Tiempo',
case when t1.U_F_Ent_Pta is null and (GETDATE()-CONVERT(time,getdate()) <= T1.ShipDate) THEN 1
when datediff(day,t0.docdate,t1.U_F_Ent_Pta) <= DATEDIFF(DAY,t0.DocDate,t1.ShipDate) then 1
else 0 end as 'Estatus Binario',
t1.U_Fecha_Rem 'Fecha Remision',
t1.U_Fecha_Arv 'Fecha de Arrivo' ,
(t1.U_F_Ent_Pta + day(7)) 'Fecha DeadLine Entrega',
DATEDIFF(DAY,t1.U_F_Ent_Pta,(t1.U_F_Ent_Pta + day(6))) as 'Tiempo de Entrega',
DATEDIFF(DAY,t1.U_F_Ent_Pta,t1.U_Fecha_Arv) as 'Tiempo de Entrega Real',
case when t1.U_Fecha_Arv is null then 'En Proceso'
when DATEDIFF(DAY,t1.U_F_Ent_Pta,t1.U_Fecha_Arv) <= DATEDIFF(DAY,t1.U_F_Ent_Pta,(t1.U_F_Ent_Pta + day(6))) then 'En Tiempo' else 'Atrasado' end as 'Mensaje Logistica',
case when t1.U_Fecha_Arv is null then 1
when DATEDIFF(DAY,t1.U_F_Ent_Pta,t1.U_Fecha_Arv) <= DATEDIFF(DAY,t1.U_F_Ent_Pta,(t1.U_F_Ent_Pta + day(6))) then 1 else 0 end as 'Mensaje Binario Logistica',
DATEDIFF(DAY,T0.DocDate,T1.U_Fecha_Arv) 'Total Dias de Entrega',
case when t1.U_Fecha_Arv is null then 'En Proceso'
when DATEDIFF(DAY,T0.DocDate,T1.U_Fecha_Arv) <= 12 then 'En Tiempo' else 'Atrasado' end as 'Mensaje Ventas',
case when t1.U_Fecha_Arv is null then 1
when DATEDIFF(DAY,T0.DocDate,T1.U_Fecha_Arv) <= 12 then 1 else 0 end as 'Mensaje Binario Ventas',
t1.WhsCode 'Codigo Almacen',
t2.WhsName 'Nombre Almacen',
case when T1.U_CAUSAI is null then 'Correcto' else T1.U_CAUSAI end as  'Causa'
from ORDR T0,RDR1 T1,OWHS T2
where T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
and t1.WhsCode = t2.WhsCode
AND T0.DocDate BETWEEN '20190101' AND getdate()
and t0.CANCELED <>'Y'
and T1.WhsCode in (01,07)
```

Comment: Por la sintaxis de la consulta, asumo que estás haciendo referencia a SQL Server. Si estás haciendo referencia a otra base de datos (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.), reemplaza la etiqueta correspondiente. Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que necesitas hacer es darle formato a tu código para ser legible. Mira la diferencia que hay con un código con formato.

```
SELECT T0.DocDate 'Fecha Pedido'
    ,YEAR(T0.DocDate) AS Año
    ,datename(MONTH, t0.DocDate) AS Mes
    ,day(t0.docdate) AS Dia
    ,T0.DocNum
    ,t0.NumAtCard
    ,T1.VendorNum
    ,t1.FreeTxt
    ,t0.CardCode
    ,t0.CardName
    ,t1.ItemCode
    ,t1.Dscription
    ,t1.Quantity
    ,T0.DocDate
    ,t1.ShipDate 'Fecha Probable de Entrega'
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY, t0.DocDate, t1.ShipDate) AS 'Dias para Entregar'
    ,t1.U_F_Ent_Pta 'Fecha Entrega Planta'
    ,datediff(day, t0.docdate, t1.U_F_Ent_Pta) AS 'Dias Entregado'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN t1.U_F_Ent_Pta IS NULL
            THEN 'En Proceso'
        ELSE 'Entregado'
        END AS 'Estatus Produccion'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN t1.U_F_Ent_Pta IS NULL
            AND (GETDATE() - CONVERT(TIME, getdate()) <= T1.ShipDate)
            THEN 'En Tiempo'
        WHEN datediff(day, t0.docdate, t1.U_F_Ent_Pta) <= DATEDIFF(DAY, t0.DocDate, t1.ShipDate)
            THEN 'En Tiempo'
        ELSE 'Atrasado'
        END AS 'Estatus Tiempo'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN t1.U_F_Ent_Pta IS NULL
            AND (GETDATE() - CONVERT(TIME, getdate()) <= T1.ShipDate)
            THEN 1
        WHEN datediff(day, t0.docdate, t1.U_F_Ent_Pta) <= DATEDIFF(DAY, t0.DocDate, t1.ShipDate)
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS 'Estatus Binario'
    ,t1.U_Fecha_Rem 'Fecha Remision'
    ,t1.U_Fecha_Arv 'Fecha de Arrivo'
    ,(t1.U_F_Ent_Pta + day(7)) 'Fecha DeadLine Entrega'
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.U_F_Ent_Pta, (t1.U_F_Ent_Pta + day(6))) AS 'Tiempo de Entrega'
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.U_F_Ent_Pta, t1.U_Fecha_Arv) AS 'Tiempo de Entrega Real'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN t1.U_Fecha_Arv IS NULL
            THEN 'En Proceso'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.U_F_Ent_Pta, t1.U_Fecha_Arv) <= DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.U_F_Ent_Pta, (t1.U_F_Ent_Pta + day(6)))
            THEN 'En Tiempo'
        ELSE 'Atrasado'
        END AS 'Mensaje Logistica'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN t1.U_Fecha_Arv IS NULL
            THEN 1
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.U_F_Ent_Pta, t1.U_Fecha_Arv) <= DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.U_F_Ent_Pta, (t1.U_F_Ent_Pta + day(6)))
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS 'Mensaje Binario Logistica'
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY, T0.DocDate, T1.U_Fecha_Arv) 'Total Dias de Entrega'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN t1.U_Fecha_Arv IS NULL
            THEN 'En Proceso'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, T0.DocDate, T1.U_Fecha_Arv) <= 12
            THEN 'En Tiempo'
        ELSE 'Atrasado'
        END AS 'Mensaje Ventas'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN t1.U_Fecha_Arv IS NULL
            THEN 1
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, T0.DocDate, T1.U_Fecha_Arv) <= 12
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS 'Mensaje Binario Ventas'
    ,t1.WhsCode 'Codigo Almacen'
    ,t2.WhsName 'Nombre Almacen'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN T1.U_CAUSAI IS NULL
            THEN 'Correcto'
        ELSE T1.U_CAUSAI
        END AS 'Causa'
FROM ORDR T0
    ,RDR1 T1
    ,OWHS T2
WHERE T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
    AND t1.WhsCode = t2.WhsCode
    AND T0.DocDate BETWEEN '20190101'
        AND getdate()
    AND t0.CANCELED <> 'Y'
    AND T1.WhsCode IN (01,07);
```

Ahora es más fácil identificar donde está la resta de `datetime` con `time`. Al parecer lo que buscas es truncar el valor de datetime para obtener solo la fecha. Para obtenerlo, puedes cambiar la parte de `GETDATE() - CONVERT(TIME, getdate())` por una de las siguientes opciones:

```
CONVERT( date, GETDATE())
DATEADD( DD, DATEDIFF( DD, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

La primera es más sencilla, pero tiene un procesamiento un poco más lento. La segunda tiene una lógica que se puede usar para truncar a cualquier punto del valor fecha/hora. Lo que hace es tomar la diferencia de la parte del valor respecto a un punto específico y luego sumarlo a ese punto. En este caso, toma los días desde la fecha cero (1900-01-01) y los suma a esa fecha. Puedes tomar cualquier fecha, pero esa funciona bien para meses y semanas que inician en lunes.